# how to get particular table row from dynamically generated table in Angular 4

Tags: angular, dom

I started working with **angular 4** and I have the following table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWfGb.jpg)
Table gets its data from http get method. Table is not empty, but I can't get to any rows of the table other than the headers. I've tried **document.getElementsByTagName('tr')** and then extracting 'td'.

In the console it show 3 rows [console.log results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvcQs.jpg)
but when I try to get length by **document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length** it shows length = 1 (this is exactly the header of the table).

From official documentation I've tried @ViewChild and @ContentChild but no luck there. Is there some other way how to work with dynamically generated table (with *ngFor) to get rows and cells?

thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you need the html of the table? Or do you only need the data? There may be another solution to what you are looking for. Angular typically shys away from direct interaction to the DOM elements and leaves that to data binding.

Comment: I agree with LLai. It might still be interesting why your code doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it's a timing issue. Your code accesses the DOM before Angular had a chance to render the bound content. Your question doesn't provide enough information to make concrete suggestions how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue when accessing table directly using document.getElementById(). So I solved it by using change detector feature in angular.

In your constructor

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){
     }
```

And in your table accessing function , before you access the table

```
function accessHtmlTable(){

        this.ref.detectChanges();
        let table = document.getElementById('id');
        //now you ll be able to see all the rows in your table
        let rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

}
```